# Query products by part of SKU

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog

For example, I have catalog with SKU's:

```
ABCDE-3
HIJKL-6
ABCDE-5
VWXYZ-6
ABCDE-21
```

I want to fetch products that have SKU that starts from `ABCDE-`, so it'll return:

```
ABCDE-3
ABCDE-5
ABCDE-21
```

Is there any way to fetch the products by part of SKU in Magento? Or I'll have to add similar products manually?

Thank you.

Comment: For internal Magento search use the code provided, if you need higher accuracy you need Sphinx (60-80% accurate) or Solr (98% accurate) which perform partial searches.

Comment: I see that you have accepted **Marius** answer. Have you used his code on a list or on product's page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$skuPart = 'ABCDE-';

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) //add default attributes to collection
            ->addMinimalPrice() // add minimal price to collection
            ->addFinalPrice() //add final price to collection
            ->addTaxPercents() //add tax percents to collection
            ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like'=>$skuPart.'%')); //filter by sku part
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection); //filter only active products
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection); //filter only products visible in catalog
```

Comment: @Marvin3. Thanks for the edit. Damn copy/paste. I forgot to check twice.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('sku', array('like' => 'ABCDE-%'));
```